# This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am working in ColdFusion 9 and I found a strange behavior on production server, specially when I am trying to invoke java functions using java object. I am not having this issue on local machine.

I am doing some calculations in first java function and storing in global variables in java file. And then trying to use in second java function, it's works well locally. I am sure there is something wrong on caching in production server but I am clueless about the issue.

Code:

```
<cfset indexSearcherObj = createObject("java", "eu.europa.ec.rtd.newindex.HIndexSearchTesting")>

<cfset strPath = ExpandPath( "./" ) />

<cfset result = indexSearcherObj.searchErasmeIndex(JavaCast("String", "ict"), JavaCast("String", "#strPath#FULLERASME"), JavaCast("String", "standard"))>
```

**Error function**

```
<cfset resultjson = indexSearcherObj.getErasmeJSONResult(JavaCast("String", "ict"), JavaCast("String", "standard"))>
```

Error Message:

Could not create disk store. This CacheManager configuration does not allow creation of DiskStores. If you wish to create DiskStores, please configure a diskStore path.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Pawan Gera